# Point Cloud visualization in Java/Android

Tags: opengl, 3d

I'm trying to visualize `.ply` point clouds (XYZRGB formatted). I was using PCL library so far. While the visualization is easy, adding features and documentation is particularly confusing and difficult for me, even worse as I'm not a C++ guy.

What are available libraries preferably in Java or Android that can efficiently visualize large `.ply` files (1M points)? I'm sure there are many less-known libraries. For instance, `jzy3d-api`. But not sure if they visualize `.ply` point cloud. No example.

What I need to do is basically read .`ply` files one after another and visualize them as if they are frames of videos. So faster, the better. I need basic features such as set Camera Views, zoom in or zoom out and others as well. A simple window like this that PCL gives me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that uses Java OpenGL Wrapper to visualize PLY file format. Here is the github [link](https://github.com/musaeed/Ply-Visualizer).

As an advice, if you want to deploy it to a mobile device, it is better to simplify and reduce the quality of mesh.

Comment: I think it doesn't visualize the colors. Shows all as red. Am I correct?

Comment: BTW, is it fast enough to visualize one model after another in a fast pace?!

Comment: I don't have information about neither available colours nor performance. I only heard about it in a forum.